# Get specific byte from M68k ram address with C language

Tags: c, gcc, memory-address, motorola

Through the IDA disassembler I've reached this address:

```
0010FD74  00 00 00 00 00 00 03 00  00 00 00 00 82 03 80 02
```

Now I need, given the address to get particular bytes; for example the 7th position where there is "03".
I've tried using C language to do this:

```
char *dummycharacter;
*dummycharacter = *(char*)0x10FD74;
```

Now if I try to access 7th value with this:

```
dummycharacter[6]
```

I don't get 0x03…where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to assign the value `dummycharacter` points to (which is pretty much nowhere, since it's not initialized). Try `dummycharacter = (char*)0x10FD74;`.