# Get specific hex from M68k ram address with C language

Tags: c, gcc, memory-address, motorola

I've got a new question related to this other one, which is solved [Get specific byte from M68k ram address with C language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27641794/get-specific-byte-from-m68k-ram-address-with-c-language)

Now my address has a full row of:

```
FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
```

which are hexadecimals.

If I tried with the same pattern of the other question, I can't get the value displayed by printf...
this is what I've done:

```
char* REG_SW;
REG_SW = (char*)0x300123;
```

then:

```
printf("H DIP SWITCHES:  %d",   REG_SW[0])
```

gives me -1

Thanks in advance and Merry XMas!!

Comment: `unsigned char* REG_SW (unsigned char*) 0x300123; printf("H DIP SWITCHES: %02X", (unsigned) REG_SW[0]);`

Answer (score 2):

In order to print the `char` value in hex form use

```
printf("H DIP SWITCHES:  %02X",   REG_SW[0])
```

Look [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/printf-format-strings.html) for `printf` tutorial, but the essence in our case is using the `X` format specifier having value printed in hex form 2 bytes wide (this is what behind the format width `02`)

EDIT- as chux observed in his comment to the question its crucial treating the register value as an unsigned type one

```
unsigned char* REG_SW (unsigned char*) 0x300123;
```

Comment: Assuming `char* REG_SW;` as OP's question, that prints `FFFFFFFF`

Comment: @WeatherVane how come FFFFFFFF ? as 02 is specified it would print FF

Comment: Because the value of 0xFF as `char` is -1, just as OP found. `%02` is the *minimum* width.

Comment: guys the answer is declaring as chux made, BUT the printf as this:
 %u",REG_SW[0]
Thanks i'll upvote everybody to helping in leading me to solution, but chux is was the closer!

Comment: @WeatherVane I'll edit my answer pinpointing the subtle signed extension issue which chux observed in his comment

Comment: Expanding on my comments, the (unsigned) `char` argument for `printf()` is converted to (unsigned) `int` before being passed. The `printf()` code itself does not know that the value came from `char`, and it is perfectly valid to pass an `int` for a `%c` format too. As for the width specifier, if a value printed does not fit the format spec, then the format will be broken and *not* the value.